# How to Inject a service into an async validator?

Tags: angular

**I have two very similar async validators**. Both check values for uniqueness: Email and initials. The first one looks like this:

```
public static createEmailUniqueValidator(userService: UserService, originalEmailAddressFn: () => string) {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => {
        const originalEmailAddress: string = originalEmailAddressFn();
        if (originalEmailAddress && originalEmailAddress === control.value) {
            return Observable.of({});
        }
        return Observable.timer(1000).switchMap(() => {
            return userService
                .isEmailAddressUnique(control.value)
                .map(result => (result ? null : { 'This email address is already in use': true }));
        });
    }
}
```

The second one almost identical, except for the method it calls on the userService. **How can I make one generic validator factory and pass it the method it should call to do the actual checking ?**

So far, I have this:

```
public static createValidator(uniqueFn: (value: string) => Observable<Boolean>, originalEmailAddressFn: () => string, errorMessage: string) {
        return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => {
            const originalEmailAddress: string = originalEmailAddressFn();
            if (originalEmailAddress && originalEmailAddress === control.value) {
                return Observable.of({});
            }
            return Observable.timer(1000).switchMap(() => {
                return uniqueFn(control.value)
                    .map(result => (result ? null : { errorMessage: true }));
            });
        }
    }
```

But I am getting the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'restService' of undefined
>       at webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/services/user/user.service.ts.UserService.isEmailAddressUnique
>   (user.service.ts:108)

restService is another service that is injected in the userService. **It looks like the dependencies have not been resolved.** How can I fix this ?

This is my userService:

```
// imports ...

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  // [...]

  constructor(private restService: RestService) { }

  isEmailAddressUnique(emailAddress: string): Observable<Boolean> {
    return this.restService.get(this.usersUrl + '/validateUniqueEmailAddress/' + emailAddress);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where `restService` is used?

Comment: Of course. Just edited my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Both misunderstood the desired number of functions, and didn't fully explain. Took the time to create a (slightly simplified) plunker that roughly matches your setup (instead of trying to check an API, it simply checks if the email is valid, but does so as an Observable; it also removes a couple parameters for `createValidator` to focus on the essential factory).

I've created a [working version](https://plnkr.co/edit/1UoRQj?p=preview), and a [non-working version](https://plnkr.co/edit/7T05Ka?p=preview). The latter successfully reproduces the error you were seeing (`Cannot read property 'restService' of undefined`) when you run it. See `src/user.service.ts` for the breaking change. And I've updated below to highlight the two functions where it's important to use the fat arrow declaration, to properly bind `this`. If there's something I've over-simplified in the plunk, do let me know, and we can work on a fork together.

Important functions for using fat arrow declaration:

```
public static = createValidator(/*same parameters*/) => {
    // same content
}
```

and

```
public isEmailAddressUnique = (/*same parameters*/) => {
    // same content
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how this helps me. I want to end up with a single createValidator method that can be given a method reference to a service.

Comment: You're very right - that was a poor explanation, and I didn't properly understand the factory function you wanted to end up with. I've updated my answer, and also spent some time on a slightly simplified plunk, linked above. Check out the non-working version to see your error reproduced, and the working version to see the function declaration I was trying to highlight.

Comment: The solution is in the rigth arrow function declaration. Nice explanattion.